# Trying to send e-mail to users that are member of AD Group and Password age equals 90

Tags: powershell

Trying to send e-mails to users that are member of a specific group and password age equals 75 days but email never sends or triggers for account with wrong password age.  Assume my "where-object" logic is at fault.

```
$NumberDays_A = 75

$EmailServer = "smtp.company.com"
$SMTPUsername = "blah@blah.com"
$MailFrom = "blah@blah.com"

$Users = get-adgroupmember "90DayPswdExpiration" |
    get-aduser -Properties SamaccountName, otherMailbox, PasswordLastSet, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordNotRequired |
    Where-Object {$(((Get-Date) - $User.PasswordLastSet).Days) -eq $NumberDays_A} 

ForEach ($User in $Users)
{
#Body of the Email using a here-string
$MailBody = @"
Hello,

You are receiving this email because your password will expire in 14.    Please coordinate the password change for this account. 

Password last set: $($User.PasswordLastSet)
Password Age: $(((Get-Date) - $User.PasswordLastSet).Days)
Password Rotation Policy:  Every 90 Days

If you need assistance with the password change please contact the Service    Desk.

Thanks you! 


"@
$MailSubject = "ACTION REQUIRED: Your AD account password must change!"
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $EmailServer -From $MailFrom -To    $($user.otherMailbox) -Subject $MailSubject -Body $MailBody
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the number of days back to 90 from current date and perform filtering with `Where-Object` cmdlet. Like so:

```
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)
$Users = Get-ADGroupMember '90DayPswdExpiration' |
            Get-ADUser -Properties SamaccountName,
                                   otherMailbox, 
                                   PasswordLastSet, 
                                   PasswordNeverExpires, 
                                   PasswordNotRequired | 
                                        Where-Object { $_.PasswordLastSet -lt $Date }
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback but what if I want to trigger the e-mail only once on the day the password age = 75  (14days before expiration)

Comment: $Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-75)
    $Users = Get-ADGroupMember '90DayPswdExpiration' |
                Get-ADUser -Properties SamaccountName,
                                       otherMailbox, 
                                       PasswordLastSet, 
                                       PasswordNeverExpires, 
                                       PasswordNotRequired | 
                                            Where-Object { $_.PasswordLastSet -eq $Date }

Comment: The following seems to work after formatting the Date variables...  Thanks a bunch for getting me track.   Very helpful!

Comment: Where-Object { $_.PasswordLastSet.ToString("yyyyMMdd") -eq $Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")}